# Disable seeing when OTHER people are last active

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

When you chat to someone it shows you at the top if they are currently active, or how long ago they were last active.
Is there a way to stop seeing this? I've already disabled my own active status, and it removes the green dots from the messages screen but it still shows when you go into the chats.